# Creating PHP API without too much traffic

Tags: php, android, performance, api

**Background:**
For an App we are building an API, right now, it works that the Client(Android) send a request every 2 seconds to check for updates.

**Question:** Is there a way, so we don't have a lot of requests for every 2 seconds?

I'm trying to find any help with PHP API development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is a websocket connection. It is, basicaly, a steady two way connection for your front-end and your backend. It listen to event and react to them.

I don't know any librairy in Java ( Android ) but i'm sure you can find one with a simple google search.

As for the PHP part of things, i've tried a few librairies and never had much luck. This was quite some times ago so maybe things have changed. I know there is [ratchet](http://socketo.me/), but at the time, i could make it work. Our solution was to send http request to a nodeJS server, on which was running a Websocket client.